# Ошибка ORA-12705 при подключении к БД Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

При подключении сторонним редактором dbeaver получаю данную ошибку ORA-12705. В реестре ключ RUSSIAN_RUSSIA.AL32UTF8, sqlplus при запросе

```
SELECT USERENV ('language') FROM DUAL
```

Также говорит что сервер использует эту языковую настройку. Через sqlplus conn /as sysdba подключается без проблем, как решить проблему помогите пожалуйста всем спасибо за помощь

Мой listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\Java\Oracle\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\Java\Oracle\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.101)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Comment: Он не видит не язык сервера, а файлы кодировок которые на клиенте. Смотреть в сторону переменной окружения NLS_LANG и особенно ORACLE_HOME (на windows может быть в реестре). Или с переменными все ок, но ему не хватает прав на чтение папки оракла

Comment: @Mike уже все что мог пересмотрел, не понимаю как решить проблему ? уже подхожу к крайним мерам переустановки бд (((

Comment: Так эта ошибка при подключении с машины на которой установлена БД. Если с путями проблема, то не понятно как она вообще стартует. Больше похоже на права доступа на папку для пользователя ОС под которым коннект. И пробовали ли подключаться снаружи, с других компов

Comment: @Mike Да это бд развернута дома на локальной машине, пользователь тут один, с наружи подкл. не пробовал

Comment: Думаю разобраться в итоге можно. но времени вагон уйдет. для начала можно попробовать переставить только клиента от той версии оракла что у вас стоит

Comment: @Mike c другого пк тоже не конектит с ошибкой ввода\вывода

Comment: @Ethernets у вас до сих пор нет ответа?

Comment: @4per добрый день, ответ найден, вам нужна помощь ?

Comment: Нет, просто хотел бы видеть ответ на этот вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу подключиться через SQLPlus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620107/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-sqlplus)

Comment: @Ethernets Не сочтите за труд, отметьте ответ как принятый, или укажите, что другое решение помогло. А то Дух каждую неделю этот топик поднимает на главную. Другое действие - закрыть вопрос как  вызваный проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте, что записано в ключах `NLS_LANG` и `ORACLE_HOME`.
Пути в реестре Windows:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` - `SOFTWARE` - `ORACLE` - `KEY_OraClient***home***`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` - `SOFTWARE` - `Wow6432Node` - `Oracle` - `KEY_OraClient***home***`

Для Linux воспользуйтесь командой `set NLS_LANG *Ваша кодировка*`