# Не могу подключиться через SQLPlus

Tags: oracle

Установил `OracleXE112_Win64`. Затем запускаю  `sqlplus`, пытаюсь подключится и получаю ошибку:

```
 SQL> connect
 Enter user-name: system
 Enter password:
 ERROR:
 ORA-01034: ORACLE not availabl
 ORA-27101: shared memory realm
 Process ID: 0
 Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Пытался также так, но безуспешно:

```
 SQL> conn / as sysdba
 ERROR:
 ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
```

Как можно просто подключится из коробки и создать просто тестовую базу и пользователя?

Comment: обычно у оракла "из коробки" базу надо создавать сразу когда его устанавливаете, там в инсталяторе пункт есть. А с помощью sqlplus это очень долго и сложно. посмотрите в меню там должны быть какие то ассистенты с их помощью можно создавать

Comment: @Mike, в том-то и дело, что при установке кроме установки пароля для юзера `System` сделать ничего нельзя

Comment: Судя по  ORA-12705 неверно настроены региональные установки. Отыщите в реестре Windows ветку HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Oracle, найдите там OracleHome От вашей установки и установите ему NLS_LANG например AMERICA_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251. Хотя, конечно, кодировка зависит от того, какой клиент используется.

Comment: Не обязательно. Такие же симтомы будут если не установлена переменная окружения ORACLE_HOME

Comment: @hinotf, это не помогло, обе переменные выставлены

Comment: Без ORACLE_HOME sqlplus вообще не запускался

Comment: Я уже давно не использовал XE, но разве его как службу в Windows запустить нельзя?

Comment: @hinotf, можно, служба также в состоянии "Работает"

Answer (score 1):

Для запуска должны быть корректно прописаны переменные (к примеру):

```
set ORACLE_SID=xe
set ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Если есть проблемы с NLS, я бы ещё прописал NLS_LANG.

```
set NLS_LANG=american_america.CL8MSWIN1251

sqlplus "/as sysdba"
```

P.S. Разумеется, это при условии, что БД создана. Если нет, то вам проще создать ее через DBCA. В Винде его можно запустить через:

```
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0>%ORACLE_HOME%\bin\dbca
```

Или в меню Пуск в папке Oracle Home - Database Configuration Assistant

Comment: В первой строчке - `set ORACLE_SID=xe`